# Spring Boot 2 deployment libraries not visible in windows shared folders

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, shared-directory

I recently started the process of migrating some of my applications from Spring Boot 1 to Spring Boot 2 when I noticed something strange.

I usually share my deployment files (i.e. the `target` folder in a spring boot application generated after calling `mvn package` ) with other members of my development team through the windows "Share..." feature. This worked well in Spring Boot 1 since the generated files would inherit the file permissions from the parent folder.

However, after migrating to Spring Boot 2, I was surprised to find that the jar files in `target/<app_name>-<ver>/WEB_INF/lib` do not inherit the file sharing preferences from the parent folder. So other members of my development team only see an empty folder instead of the applications `jar` dependencies.

Strangely, this does not seem to affect any of the other files in the target folder (static files, class files etc.).

Is this a feature or a bug? Is there a way to make sure that the files in this folder are being shared properly?

I have created a batch file that I can run after calling `mvn package` but this is an extra step that I would like to avoid.

Comment: ...don't "share your target folders" share *source* folders! (only)...you have maven! (share your/introduce a repo)